# .Element Ambiguous use of Element SWXMLHash swift

Tags: swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

[Push Notifications Tutorial: Getting Started](https://www.raywenderlich.com/584-push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started) from raywenderlich, when build the start project, The error show:

```
.Element Ambiguous use of Element SWXMLHash swift
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the  starter project of WenderCast from [Push Notifications Tutorial: Getting Started](https://www.raywenderlich.com/584-push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started),
Because the starter project is built error, I correct it. Finally can run. The correct solution is below.
 1. change the `SWXMLHash.swift` file from [drmohundro/SWXMLHash](https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash), for the problem 
 `.Element Ambiguous use of Element SWXMLHash swift`
 2. correct the code in file `PodcastFeedLoader.swift` in line 48 to   
   `let feedItems = items.all.flatMap { (indexer: XMLIndexer) -> PodcastItem? in` , 
   the origin code is 
 `let feedItems = items.flatMap { (indexer: XMLIndexer) -> PodcastItem? in`

The correct the project in github: https://github.com/zgpeace/WenderCast-Starter